# Operations in Convolution layer in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-serving, tensor

I'm reading about the convolution for deep learning with TF, with source code is here [Deep learning with Tensorflow](https://gist.github.com/dandelionmane/4f02ab8f1451e276fea1f165a20336f1#file-mnist-py) . I read about the definition of convolution layer:

```
       def conv_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="conv"):
         with tf.name_scope(name):
           w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
           b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
           conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
           act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
           return tf.nn.max_pool(act, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")
```

Although I read about some related documents, but still I don't understand exactly the meaning of each entry in

```
      [5, 5, size_in, size_out]
```

and the meaning of the following code:

```
      act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
      return tf.nn.max_pool()
```

Could you help me with this basic question?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start reading the official tutorials, and only afterwards code of some people who took official tutorials and slightly [modified](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) it by removing comments and explanations.

Your `[5, 5, size_in, size_out]` is shape of a variable passed in [conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d), which by reading documentation is

> kernel tensor of shape [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]

in_channels is the number of channels in the input image. For greyscale images it is 1, for RGB is 3. Out_channels is an arbitrary number.

The meaning of this code

```
act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
tf.nn.max_pool()
```

is the standard block of CNN, relu and maxpooling. There is a ton of information written about each definition.

Comment: @ Salvador Dali:  thanks for your answer. As my understanding, size_out is out_channels, and it is the number of filters of each convolution layer, so it depends on our choice, right?

Comment: @ChuongNguyen yes. You can put anything there